# Error running GraphicsMagick on Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, graphicsmagick

I've installed the `GraphicsMagick` and the gem on the local machine which runs the rails server, and it worked well. However, on the dev server, the environment is setup using `Passenger` and `Apache`. I've installed the `GraphicsMagick` and did a `bundle install`. It did install the gem successfully.

However, when I access the site, I am getting the following error:

```
There was an error while trying to load the gem 'graphicsmagick'.
Gem Load Error is: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - mkmf.log
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:308:in `initialize'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:308:in `open'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:308:in `log_open'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:317:in `open'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1574:in `find_executable'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/graphicsmagick-1.0.5/lib/graphicsmagick.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/AdvanceX/backend/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/AdvanceX/backend/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/AdvanceX/backend/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:3:in `require'
config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `<main>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `eval'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `preload_app'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
 (Bundler::GemRequireError)
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
  /home/ubuntu/AdvanceX/backend/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/ubuntu/AdvanceX/backend/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
  /home/ubuntu/AdvanceX/backend/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `eval'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the user running the app didn't have sufficient `permission` to run `find_executable` nor write access to create the `mkmf.log` log file.

Adding a `usergroup` with sufficient access to the user solved the issue.